# Value in Android not being passed to PHP

Tags: php, android

I have an activity in Android Studio that is supposed to pass input date into a SQL Database through a PHP script. All values get passed through except the `username` value. I also am not too familiar with PHP and Android Studio, I'm learning from tutorials right now.

Here is the relevent code in Android Studio. (I gave them literal string values to test to see if the `username` variable was the issue, and it is not, all the other values get passed through).

```
super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("name",  "name");
params.put("password", "password");
params.put("username", "username");
params.put("age", age + "");
```

And here is the PHP Script that is passing those values into the SQL Database. (I added generic `$con` information, but the real script does have the real information.)

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect(Host, User, Password, Database);

$name = $_POST["name"];
$age = $_POST["age"];
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO user (name, username, age, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss", $name, $username, $age, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = true;  

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

All other values get passed through and saved in the Database without issue, the only one having a problem is the `username` value, it keeps returning `0` no matter what I try. I even tried a php mail script so it could email me the variable it is receiving, and it is receiving a `0` if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change from

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss", $name, $username, $age, $password);
//                                   /\
```

to

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ssis", $name, $username, $age, $password);
//                                   /\
```

---

If you take a look at the [types parameter](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#refsect1-mysqli-stmt.bind-param-parameters), you'll see that your code is actually representing this:

- `$name     (s)` - string
- `$username (i)` - **integer**
- `$age      (s)` - string
- `$password (s)` - string

So, you are basically 'saying' that your `$username` is an integer. That's why you get `0`.

Comment: You are a savior! Thank you so much, that was frustrating me for days.